# Save Path from CGContext in Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I'm trying to write a small drawing app for macOS in Swift using Cocoa. The problem is that the last drawn line disappears when the `NSView` is drawn again. Is there a way to keep the drawn lines? I could save the points in an array, but that would drastically decrease the performance. Unfortunately, the `CGContextSaveGState` function doesn't save paths.

Here's my class for the `NSView` I'm drawing in (with a mouse or a stylus):

```
import Cocoa

class DrawingView: NSView {
  // Variables

  var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
  var currentPoint = CGPoint.zero

  var red: CGFloat = 0.0
  var green: CGFloat = 0.0
  var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
  var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0

  var brushSize: CGFloat = 2.0

  var dragged = false

  // Draw function

  override func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)

    let context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)

    if !dragged {
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
    } else {
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)

      lastPoint = currentPoint
    }

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushSize)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, alpha)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Normal)

    CGContextDrawPath(context, .Stroke)
  }

  // Mouse event functions

  override func mouseDown(event: NSEvent) {
    dragged = false

    lastPoint = event.locationInWindow

    self.setNeedsDisplayInRect(self.frame)
  }

  override func mouseDragged(event: NSEvent) {
    dragged = true

    currentPoint = event.locationInWindow

    self.setNeedsDisplayInRect(self.frame)
  }

  override func mouseUp(event: NSEvent) {
    self.setNeedsDisplayInRect(self.frame)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, I'd step out of CoreGraphics and use `NSBezierPath`. You can save that in a property. You can then just call `lineToPoint` as more points come in and then call `stroke` to draw it. For example:

```
let strokeColor = NSColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)

let path = NSBezierPath()
path.lineWidth = brushSize
path.lineCapStyle = .RoundLineCapStyle
path.lineJoinStyle = .RoundLineJoinStyle

path.moveToPoint(lastPoint)
path.lineToPoint(currentPoint)
...

strokeColor.setStroke()
path.stroke()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for CGContextCopyPath. It hands you a CGPath pseudo-object. The easiest way to preserve that it is to stuff into an NSBezierPath as its `path`, because an NSBezierPath is a *real* object and ARC will memory-manage it for you.